# Excel App for SO

Tags: discussion, stackapps

I created a small Excel App for Stackoverflow Users (Deliberately didn't create it in VB.Net as I was not sure if I can upload an Exe file) which will let you find out how many votes are left to get a Bronze/Silver/Gold in a particular Tag say For `VB.Net`, `C#`, `VBA-Excel` or any other. it also gets the bifurcation of the points vs votes.

Where do I post it? Is http://stackapps.com the right place to post it or do I post it here? I searched stackapps but couldn't find a similar app that has been posted there.

FOLLOWUP

App posted at [STACKAPP](https://stackapps.com/questions/3527/badge-status-for-a-particular-tag-in-stackoverflow)

Comment: Can't you already do this? Do people need an app to subtract, say, 555 from 1000? http://i.stack.imgur.com/1KK5y.png

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Does it give you the bifurcation?

Comment: The app sounds like a great idea.  Post it soon so I can free up some space on my whiteboard.  ;)

Comment: @Siddharth Do you mean does your profile page show you how many votes you've received and how many questions you've received them on? Yes, it does. Did you click on my image link?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: No. One moment. Uploading a pic

Comment: I guess I don't understand what value that adds. <shrug>

Comment: @AaronBertrand: If I am curious on about the votes bifurcation then yes that is an imp info for me. Also that info can be used to calculate more info about `Nice Answers`, `Great Answers` etc... Though the App doesn't do this at the moment but I will be adding it in the future...

Comment: You keep saying "bifurcation" and what I'm saying is that even after seeing your screen shot I have no idea what those 9- 8- 7- etc. mean. Does your app come with some kind of documentation to explain what you mean by bifurcation and what I can do differently based on those bifurcation values?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I see what you mean. Good suggestion. I might as well make a VB.Net App which comes with the help files and an installer.

Comment: You could still explain it here. I won't be installing your app just so I can view the help files to figure out what additional information that gives me and how I can't get those badges without it...

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have a list of about a dozen tags that I'm close to getting a badge in.  The top 2 or 3 are easily found near the top of my list of frequent tags, but the rest are scattered around the list.  It would be nice to have an app I can run periodically to quickly tell me if I'm getting close in any others so I can decide if I want to shift my focus.  (That is, when my focus actually shifts to answering questions, which is rare these days.)

Comment: @BilltheLizard: That sounds interesting. Currently the App looks for only 1 Tag. Do you think the ability to specify say max 5 tags separated by comma would benefit anyone? Aaron, I am making few changes to the app. Will post the sceenshots soon. It will show the user an analysis + Graph + also show what those bifurcations are...

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yeah, ideally I'd like to see a list of all the badges I'm close to getting.  Maybe show all the badges that I'm within 10% of the required votes for?  There are also some tags where I already have enough votes, I just haven't answered enough questions yet.  That should probably be a separate category.  I've been thinking of writing a script like this myself, since manually updating a whiteboard or spreadsheet is a pain.  Plus, I need to go look for new badges that I'm getting close to.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Would something like this be of any use? Please feel free to suggest improvements. http://wikisend.com/download/321312/Untitled.png

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Good idea! Will try and incorporate it.. Might as well make a good job out of it :)

Comment: If you need to create an installer for this let me know. I already have an Inno Setup script to install addins. We could always post it on another site if stackapps won't allow it.

Comment: @JP: Thanks :) I already have an installer which I use for Add-Ins. I use `Advanced Installer 9.0`

Comment: OK. I wonder how else we could leverage VBA with the SO API, and if anyone else has anything similar.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Your Thoughts please... since it is your ID ;). http://wikisend.com/download/380836/1.png AND http://wikisend.com/download/403504/2.png

Comment: @AaronBertrand: And this one's for you. Your thoughts please. http://wikisend.com/download/610140/1.png AND http://wikisend.com/download/445524/2.png

Comment: Take the discussion of the app to Stack Apps, please.

Comment: @AnnaLear: Done. Editing my question for the link.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, StackApps is the right place to post it.